Стрелочки слайдера не работают. Ошибок никаких нет
Почему не работает переключение - я не понимаю. Функции следующий и назад написаны. Я их в код установил. Ошибок никаких нету. Проверял с выводом в консоль сообщения и цифры, всё работало +1 -1 и так далее. Но слайдер не переключается. И вообще никак не реагирует.


import React, {
  useState
} from 'react';

const ShowCase = () => {
    const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);
    const handlePrev = () => setActiveSlide(activeSlide - 1);
    const handleNext = () => setActiveSlide(activeSlide + 1);
    return ( <
        div className = 'Showcase_item__ajKek' >
        <
        div >
        <
        div className = 'common_line__9RJLR common_line_type_promo-editors___GaUP PromoVideoline_line__iqVKv PromoVideoline_line_type_promo-editors__0Mf2V'
        data - gtm - vis - first - on - screen11350452_351 = "939"
        data - gtm - vis - total - visible - time11350452_351 = "100"
        data - gtm - vis - has - fired11350452_351 = "1" >
        <
        div className = 'Header_header__YhTu_ PromoVideoline_header__v2m27' >
        <
        div className = 'Header_wrapper__rgWJb' >
        <
        h2 className = 'Header_title__n1TZ2' > Новое в Flixo < /h2> <
        /div> <
        /div> <
        div className = 'Slider_slider__RbzAd'
        style = {
          {
            '--slideToShow': '5',
            '--slides-offset': '16px'
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'Slider_btn__B8Qtp Slider_btn_prev__xfwu8 PromoVideoline_sliderButton__7NopD Slider_btn_visible__LJrxs'
        onClick = {
          handlePrev
        }
        style = {
          {
            backgroundImage: `url(${left})`
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'Slider_btnArrow__Aafu_' > < /div> <
        /div> <
        div className = 'Slider_btn__B8Qtp Slider_btn_next__xB4sg PromoVideoline_sliderButton__7NopD Slider_btn_visible__LJrxs'
        onClick = {
          handleNext
        }
        style = {
          {
            backgroundImage: `url(${right})`
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'Slider_btnArrow__Aafu_' > < /div> <
        /div> <
        div className = 'Slider_container__v97Np PromoVideoline_sliderContainer__RcVni' >
        <
        div className = 'Slider_wrapper__O8hJs PromoVideoline_sliderWrapper__rq6Hq'
        style = {
          {
            transform: 'translateX(0px)'
          }
        } >
        <
        div data - slideindex = "0"
        className = 'Slider_slide__prVHT Slider_slide_in_view___jKkg' >
        <
        a className = 'common_card_type_promo-editors__39291 UniversalPromoCard_card__XDJE_'
        href = "#"
        style = {
          {
            zIndex: 1000
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_imageWrapper__81un3'
        style = {
          {
            color: 'rgb(31, 33, 37)'
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_imageWrapper__UD20K'
        style = {
          {
            backgroundImage: `url(${image1})`,
            clipPath: 'polygon(0% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)'
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_ageRestrictions__wKovT' > 18 + < /div> <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_gradient__Oyt0j UniversalPromoCard_gradient_preset_layered-poster__VCnPW UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_shadow__bk_Bw UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_accent__CDZ8Z UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_cornerShadow__l90XL' > < /div> <
        img className = 'UniversalPromoCard_logo__kakl2'
        src = {
          logo1
        }
        alt = ""
        style = {
          {
            marginTop: `100%`,
            width: '100%',
            height: 'auto'
          }
        }
        /> <
        /div> <
        /div> <
        span className = 'visually-hidden' > HALO < /span> <
        /a> <
        /div> <
        div data - slideindex = "1"
        className = 'Slider_slide__prVHT Slider_slide_in_view___jKkg' >
        <
        a className = 'common_card_type_promo-editors__39291 UniversalPromoCard_card__XDJE_'
        href = "#"
        style = {
          {
            zIndex: 999
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_imageWrapper__81un3'
        style = {
          {
            color: 'rgb(31, 33, 37)'
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_imageWrapper__UD20K'
        style = {
          {
            backgroundImage: `url(${image2})`,
            clipPath: 'polygon(0% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)'
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_ageRestrictions__wKovT' > 18 + < /div> <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_gradient__Oyt0j UniversalPromoCard_gradient_preset_layered-poster__VCnPW UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_shadow__bk_Bw UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_accent__CDZ8Z UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_cornerShadow__l90XL' > < /div> <
        img className = 'UniversalPromoCard_logo__kakl2'
        src = {
          logo2
        }
        alt = ""
        style = {
          {
            marginTop: `90%`,
            width: '100%',
            height: 'auto'
          }
        }
        /> <
        /div> <
        /div> <
        span className = 'visually-hidden' > Призраки < /span> <
        /a> <
        /div> <
        div data - slideindex = "2"
        className = 'Slider_slide__prVHT Slider_slide_in_view___jKkg' >
        <
        a className = 'common_card_type_promo-editors__39291 UniversalPromoCard_card__XDJE_'
        href = "#"
        style = {
          {
            zIndex: 998
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_imageWrapper__81un3'
        style = {
          {
            color: 'rgb(31, 33, 37)'
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_imageWrapper__UD20K'
        style = {
          {
            backgroundImage: `url(${image3})`,
            clipPath: 'polygon(0% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)'
          }
        } >
        <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_ageRestrictions__wKovT' > 18 + < /div> <
        div className = 'UniversalPromoCard_gradient__Oyt0j UniversalPromoCard_gradient_preset_layered-poster__VCnPW UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_shadow__bk_Bw UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_accent__CDZ8Z UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_cornerShadow__l90XL' > < /div> <
        img className = 'UniversalPromoCard_logo__kakl2'
        src = {
          logo3
        }
        alt = ""
        style = {
          {
            marginTop: `100%`,
            width: '100%',
            height: 'auto'
          }
        }
        /> <
        /div> <
        /div> <
        span className = 'visually-hidden' > Хорошая борьба < /span> <
        /a> <
        /div>
/* Стрелка Назад*/

.Slider_btn_prev__xfwu8 {
  left: 0;
}

.Slider_btn__B8Qtp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  width: calc(80px - 16px);
  height: 100%;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
}

.Slider_btn_prev__xfwu8.Slider_btnArrow__Aafu_ {
  background-image: url(/src/Components/Assets/Arrows/left.svg);
}

.Slider_btnArrow__Aafu_ {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  background-size: 20px;
  transition: transform .25s ease;
}


/* Стрелка Вперед*/

.Slider_btn_visible__LJrxs {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.Slider_btn_next__xB4sg {
  right: 0;
}

.Slider_btn_next__xB4sg.Slider_btnArrow__Aafu_ {
  background-image: url(/src/Components/Assets/Arrows/right.svg);
}






const images = [
    { url: image1, logo: logo1, title: 'HALO' },
    { url: image2, logo: logo2, title: 'Призраки' },
    { url: image3, logo: logo3, title: 'Хорошая борьба' },
    { url: image4, logo: logo4, title: 'Название 4' },
    { url: image5, logo: logo5, title: 'Название 5' },
    { url: image6, logo: logo6, title: 'Название 6' },
    { url: image7, logo: logo7, title: 'Название 7' },
    { url: image8, logo: logo8, title: 'Название 7' },
    { url: image9, logo: logo9, title: 'Название 7' },
    { url: image10, logo: logo10, title: 'Название 8' },
    { url: image11, logo: logo11, title: 'Название 9' },
    { url: image12, logo: logo12, title: 'Название 10' },
    { url: image13, logo: logo13, title: 'Название 11' },
  ];

const ShowCase = () => {
    const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(0);
    const handlePrev = () => setActiveSlide(Math.max(activeSlide - 1, 0));
    const handleNext = () => setActiveSlide(Math.min(activeSlide + 1, images.length - 4));
    
        return (
            <div className='Showcase_item__ajKek'>
                <div>
                    <div className='common_line__9RJLR common_line_type_promo-editors___GaUP PromoVideoline_line__iqVKv PromoVideoline_line_type_promo-editors__0Mf2V'
                    data-gtm-vis-first-on-screen11350452_351="939" data-gtm-vis-total-visible-time11350452_351="100" data-gtm-vis-has-fired11350452_351="1"  >
                        <div className='Header_header__YhTu_ PromoVideoline_header__v2m27'>
                            <div className='Header_wrapper__rgWJb'>
                                <h2 className='Header_title__n1TZ2'>Новое в Flixo</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='Slider_slider__RbzAd' style={{'--slideToShow': '5', '--slides-offset': '16px'}}>
                            <div className='Slider_btn__B8Qtp Slider_btn_prev__xfwu8 PromoVideoline_sliderButton__7NopD Slider_btn_visible__LJrxs' onClick={handlePrev} style={{backgroundImage: `url(${left})`}}>
                                    <div className='Slider_btnArrow__Aafu_'></div>
                                </div>
                            <div className='Slider_btn__B8Qtp Slider_btn_next__xB4sg PromoVideoline_sliderButton__7NopD Slider_btn_visible__LJrxs' onClick={handleNext} style={{backgroundImage: `url(${right})`}}>
                                <div className='Slider_btnArrow__Aafu_'></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='Slider_container__v97Np PromoVideoline_sliderContainer__RcVni' >
                                <div className='Slider_wrapper__O8hJs PromoVideoline_sliderWrapper__rq6Hq' style={{transform: 'translateX(0px)'}}> 
                                {images.slice(activeSlide, activeSlide + 13).map((image, index) => (
                                <div key={index} data-slideindex={activeSlide + index} className={`Slider_slide__prVHT Slider_slide_in_view___jKkg ${activeSlide === index ? 'active' : ''}`} >
                                    <a className='common_card_type_promo-editors__39291 UniversalPromoCard_card__XDJE_' href="#" style={{zIndex: 1000 - index}}>
                                        <div className='UniversalPromoCard_imageWrapper__81un3' style={{color: 'rgb(31, 33, 37)'}}>
                                            <div className='UniversalPromoCard_imageWrapper__UD20K' style={{backgroundImage: `url(${image.url})`, clipPath: 'polygon(0% 5%, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0% 100%)'}}>
                                                <div className='UniversalPromoCard_ageRestrictions__wKovT'>18+</div>
                                                <div className='UniversalPromoCard_gradient__Oyt0j UniversalPromoCard_gradient_preset_layered-poster__VCnPW UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_shadow__bk_Bw UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_accent__CDZ8Z UniversalPromoCard_gradient_with_cornerShadow__l90XL' ></div>
                                                <img className='UniversalPromoCard_logo__kakl2' src={image.logo} alt="" style={{marginTop: `${[1].includes(activeSlide + index + 1) ? '105%' : [12].includes(activeSlide + index + 1) ? '65%' : [10].includes(activeSlide + index + 1) ? '85%' :[7].includes(activeSlide + index + 1) ? '80%' : [2].includes(activeSlide + index + 1) ? '90%' : '100%'}`, width: '100%', height: 'auto'}}/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <span className='visually-hidden'>{image.title}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>))}



